# JavaScript - Transform Object to Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I'm looking to convert the import below into the output. I think there is way to do this with `.reduce()`, or `Object.keys()`, or `for...in` loop, maybe something else but I'm not 100% certain.

Any help would be amazing. Code snippet if possible?

Input:

```
{a_b_c: 1, a_b_d: 2, a_e: 3, f_g: 4}
```

Output:

```
{a: { b: {c: 1, d: 2}, e: 3 }, f: {g: 4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), you can split at the underscore and use [`set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set):

```js
const data = {a_b_c: 1, a_b_d: 2, a_e: 3, f_g: 4};

const res = Object.entries(data).reduce((res, [key, val]) => {
  _.set(res, key.split('_'), val);
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js "></script>
```